# Git asking SSH key password

Tags: git, ssh

I'm using Git to clone my repository from Github. I'm using HTTPS to clone it.

Everytime I `cd` to the repository, or every command I do, the terminal asks me my SSH key password. This is strange, since I'm not using SSH to connect to Github.

If I type my SSH key password, the terminal hangs. If I just ignore it (pressing return), everything works fine, however it keeps asking my SSH password every new command.

I don't have a clue what can it be, and I'm having this problem with two repositories that contains javascript code.

Thanks in advance

Edit: `git config --show-origin -l` returns this:

```
file:/usr/local/etc/gitconfig   credential.helper=osxkeychain
file:/Users/otaviobonder/.gitconfig     user.name=Otavio Bonder
file:/Users/otaviobonder/.gitconfig     user.email=xxxxxx
file:/Users/otaviobonder/.gitconfig     core.autocrlf=input
file:.git/config        core.repositoryformatversion=0
file:.git/config        core.filemode=true
file:.git/config        core.bare=false
file:.git/config        core.logallrefupdates=true
file:.git/config        core.ignorecase=true
file:.git/config        core.precomposeunicode=true
file:.git/config        remote.origin.url=https://github.com/otaviobps/TransferEasy_newFrontEnd.git
file:.git/config        remote.origin.fetch=+refs/heads/*:refs/remotes/origin/*
file:.git/config        branch.master.remote=origin
file:.git/config        branch.master.merge=refs/heads/master
Enter passphrase for key '/Users/otaviobonder/.ssh/id_rsa':
```

I just suppressed my email address

Edit 2: I'm using `zsh`, and I can see that after every command, it runs a `SSH` command automatically, because I see the terminal window title changes to `SSH`, but I don't know why and which command

Edit 3: Here is the `.zshrc` configuration:

```
# Example format: plugins=(rails git textmate ruby lighthouse)
# Add wisely, as too many plugins slow down shell startup.
plugins=(git)


# User configuration

# export MANPATH="/usr/local/man:$MANPATH"

# You may need to manually set your language environment
# export LANG=en_US.UTF-8

# Preferred editor for local and remote sessions
# if [[ -n $SSH_CONNECTION ]]; then
#   export EDITOR='vim'
# else
#   export EDITOR='mvim'
# fi

# Compilation flags
# export ARCHFLAGS="-arch x86_64"

# ssh
# export SSH_KEY_PATH="~/.ssh/rsa_id"

# Set personal aliases, overriding those provided by oh-my-zsh libs,
# plugins, and themes. Aliases can be placed here, though oh-my-zsh
# users are encouraged to define aliases within the ZSH_CUSTOM folder.
# For a full list of active aliases, run `alias`.
#
# Example aliases
# alias zshconfig="mate ~/.zshrc"
# alias ohmyzsh="mate ~/.oh-my-zsh"

export NVM_DIR="$HOME/.nvm"
[ -s "$NVM_DIR/nvm.sh" ] && \. "$NVM_DIR/nvm.sh"  # This loads nvm
[ -s "$NVM_DIR/bash_completion" ] && \. "$NVM_DIR/bash_completion"  # This loads nvm bash_completion

### Added by Plugin's installer
source '/Users/otaviobonder/.zplugin/bin/zplugin.zsh'
autoload -Uz _zplugin
(( ${+_comps} )) && _comps[zplugin]=_zplugin
### End of Zplugin's installer chunk

zplugin light zdharma/fast-syntax-highlighting
zplugin light zsh-users/zsh-autosuggestions
zplugin light zsh-users/zsh-history-substring-search
zplugin light zsh-users/zsh-completions
zplugin light buonomo/yarn-completion

pasteinit() {
  OLD_SELF_INSERT=${${(s.:.)widgets[self-insert]}[2,3]}
  zle -N self-insert url-quote-magic # I wonder if you'd need `.url-quote-magic`?
}

pastefinish() {
  zle -N self-insert $OLD_SELF_INSERT
}
zstyle :bracketed-paste-magic paste-init pasteinit
zstyle :bracketed-paste-magic paste-finish pastefinish


# Simplify prompt if we're using Hyper
if [[ "$TERM_PROGRAM" == "Hyper" ]]; then
  SPACESHIP_PROMPT_SEPARATE_LINE=false
  SPACESHIP_DIR_SHOW=false
  SPACESHIP_GIT_BRANCH_SHOW=false
fi
  # Set Spaceship ZSH as a prompt
  autoload -U promptinit; promptinit
  prompt spaceship
```

I tried to disable the git plugin, but the issue persists

Comment: can you show the result of `git remote -v` please

Comment: `➜ git remote -v`
`origin https://github.com/otaviobps/TransferEasy_newBackEnd.git (fetch)`
`origin https://github.com/otaviobps/TransferEasy_newBackEnd.git (push)`

Comment: `git clone` and the https address. This is happening just with two repositories. My others repositories don't have this issue

Comment: is that the ssh key asked or the github password?

Comment: It's asking the SSH key. My github credentials are set globally

Answer (score 0):

It should not be asking for any "SSH" data (password/passphrase/...)

You are using an HTTPS URL, so check first the output of `git config credential.helper`: you might have to reset cached credentials there (in the [Windows Credentials Manager](https://stackoverflow.com/a/39592537/6309) or [OSX KeyChain](https://help.github.com/en/articles/updating-credentials-from-the-osx-keychain) for Mac).

> My github credentials are set globally

Make sure you don't mean `user.name`/`user.email`: those are not GitHub credentials.

---

If it does ask for the passphrase on *every* command, check "[How to fix: MacOS keep asking passphrase for ssh key after upgrade or reboots](https://www.cyberciti.biz/faq/howto-fix-macos-keeps-asking-my-ssh-passphrase-since-i-updated-to-sierra/)"

```
$ vi ~/.ssh/config

Host *
  UseKeychain yes
```

Comment: `cd TransferEasy_newBackEnd`
`Enter passphrase for key '/Users/otaviobonder/.ssh/id_rsa':`
It's asking for SSH key password, not Github password. My github credentials (username and password) are set globally. I never need to type them. This is just happening with two repositories, so I guess it's not a problem with credentials. I already deleted and cloned it again, but this won't fix the issue

Comment: @OtavioBonder Interesting: you could add that to your question.

Comment: @OtavioBonder "My github credentials (username and password) are set globally.": what does that mean? *How* are they set globally?

Comment: they are cached

Comment: @OtavioBonder in the OSX KeyChain? What OS  are you using? What version of Git are you using?

Comment: Yes, in OSX KeyChain. Git version 2.21.0. OSX 10.14.5

Comment: @OtavioBonder Would the link I mention in my edited answer be helpful in your case?

Comment: Unfortunatelly no. It just starts asking the SSH password when I enter in the repository directory. And it shouldn't ask, because it's not configured to use SSH, and even if I type the password, the terminal hangs. It just works without using the SSH key

Comment: @OtavioBonder Did you modify the ~/.ssh/config (as mentioned in the answer)?

Comment: No. My SSH key works fine to login to my remote servers. I really have no idea why it's asking the SSH key for this repo. I think it's some configuration in the repo, but I don't know which one

Comment: @OtavioBonder OK, can you edit your question with `git config --show-origin -l`, as done from within your local repository?

Comment: @OtavioBonder Maybe the content of `~/.zshenv` or `~/.zshrc` is relevant here.

Comment: @OtavioBonder Any zsh plugin (https://github.com/unixorn/awesome-zsh-plugins) installed? (like https://github.com/jeffwalter/zsh-plugin-cd-ssh)